# Can I use Elasticache Memcached to store the events which the value has JSON object in key-value pair

Tags: caching, redis, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to push the events into the cache. The events contain a key-value pair. The key is a string and "Value" is a JSON object. Can I use memcached for this(I have read somewhere that in memcached we can use only strings, but here I'm using a JSON object as value). Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should check RedisJSON module for Redis. See - https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to serialize the JSON object to a text string before storing it with Memcached

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).